# Qtcreator freezes after few minutes of use

Tags: 16.04, qt, qt-creator

I just installed Qt 4.1.0 
`Based on Qt 5.7.0 (GCC 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10), 64 bit)`
And every time I run it after a few minutes of use it freezes.
I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, on a laptop (Lenovo G510)
`ubuntu-drivers devices` output:

```
== cpu-microcode.py ==
driver   : intel-microcode - distro non-free
```

`lspci -nn | grep VGA` output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06)
```

Any idea what's the problem?

Edit: after disabling both `Welcome` and  `QmlDesigner` plugins, it doesn't crash. But now I can't see the examples&Tutorials and use the Qt Design

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator/+bug/1577213 probably related

Answer (score 0):

Even with the current latest Qt Creator 6+, this issue happens when you compile a large project with some C++ header file changes. It happens even with few small consecutive compilations. **This issue persists even after closing the Qt Creator.**

Unfortunately there is no known fix yet, as it appears that Qt is spawning separate processes for threaded compilations. One may go to

> Projects > Builds & Run > [Desktop version] > Build > Build Steps >
> Make > Parallel jobs

Choose a smaller number such as 1 or 2. But this is not consistently helpful. To make the matter worse, sometimes it may make the compilation very slow.

Suppose, if this problem happens even after closing then there is a **workaround** for Ubuntu. Run below command after closing:

```
ps -ef | grep -i qt
```

This will list the processes still attached with the Qt Creator even after it was closed. Such as:

```
milind      1962    1759  0 07:25 ?        00:00:43 /home/milind/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator
milind      2669    1962  0 07:26 ?        00:00:00 /home/milind/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/../libexec/qtcreator/qtcreator_processlauncher /tmp/QtCreator-FXruRe/launcher-1962
milind      3588    2669  0 07:28 ?        00:00:27 /home/milind/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/libexec/qtcreator/clangbackend /tmp/QtCreator-FXruRe/ClangBackEnd-1962
milind     10772    5095  0 11:37 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i qt
```

Killing the topmost process kills all the subprocesses too.

> **kill -9 [pid]** // in above case it was 1962

Afterwards, opening the Qt Creator will feel like a stable and a new incarnation!