# Qtcreator hangs and crashes

Tags: qt-creator

I have a big problem with Qtcreator

I can't even write a code because it hangs/crashes whenever I bring up Qtcreator on ubuntu 16.04.

I have Qt Creator 3.5.1

Based on Qt 5.5.1 (GCC 5.2.1 20151129, 64 bit).

I got it from synaptic.

I'll appreciate Any help to fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had the same issue, 3.5.1 is super buggy. I fixed the problem by getting 4.2.1 from the [Qt Online Installer](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/).

Comment: Thank you so much! that's solved the problem. but how can I bring up Qt by command "Qtcreator" in the terminal, without going to it's file?

Comment: I just use the Ubuntu applications launcher to open Qt Creator - that's way easier. That said, if you still really want to launch it that way, you can add ``<path to Qt folder here>/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin`` to your PATH (Google how to do that) and then doing ``qtcreator`` to work.

Comment: Even with Qt 6.0, this issue happens sometimes after a long compilations. See if [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841379/qtcreator-freezes-after-few-minutes-of-use/1505714#1505714) helps for such users.